# ESP32 custom board not receiving code

Tags: esp32, cp2102

I'm trying to program one ESP32 custom board with a CP2102 USB, I followed the schematic of the [official datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf) but when I try to upload my code the board doesn't recieve the code but the TX led shining :

[image]

This is my schematic:

[image]

I tried also wiring the EN and GND pin but with the same result, and adding one 25 uF capacitor between EN and GND, does anyone have any idea where my fault is?

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Have you measured that supply voltages are OK? Have you verifed that the devices you have connected to ESP32 do not interfere with the boot straps? How do you even make the device to go into programming mode? Also don't connect any supply to DC jack, as the LM2576 circuit is completely wrong and can do some damage.

Comment: aside from the problem, you shouldn't place the ESP32 that way. the antenna shouldn't be placed near PCB tracks or power planes or any kind of copper as mentioned in the hardware design guide of espressif.

Comment: Is there a boot button on the board? On my ESP-modules there is one. I need to press it to allow the connection.

Comment: @Justme I just saw that the pin 5 of LM2576 it's wrong, It should be connected to GND, right? The voltaje for upload the code is right the ESP32 have 3.3v https://i.imgur.com/e0Rg6bb.jpeg and the pins Tx and Rx of the CP2102 have the correct conection to esp32. For the moment, the board only have the esp32, a buzzer and the LM2576 so it shouldn't have interference. It into programming mode with a bridge into GND and EN pins.

Comment: @Bart no I don't included a boot button in the design but this button it's a bridge into EN and GND pin, when I do the bridge manually, the result it's the same, with the capacitor you simulate this bridge into EN and GND pins

Comment: @Tirdad Sadri Nejad thanks I will take it into account for the following prototypes

Comment: @mourazo no the whole output circuit of the smps is incorrectly connected, it will not output 5V and if you had something connected there is a possibility that input voltage is connected to 5V node via capacitor, just compare your schematic with the datasheet schematic.

Comment: @Justme yes, I don't know why I did this scheme, maybe I found it in another easy eda project, do you think it may have something to do with the uploading code problem?

Comment: @mourazo if you have never connected anything to it, it should not prevent things from working. That's why I told you to measure if supply voltages are OK, did you? On a side note, why have you connected TX to TX and RX to RX? That can't be correct, right?

Comment: No, when I upload the code the Tx of the CP2102 it's wiring to de Rx of the esp32 and the Rx CP2102 with the Tx of the ESP32

Comment: EN is the reset pin. You need to pull IO0 low to put the esp32 into boot mode. Refer to the esp32 devkitC schematics. Your psu layout is not good. Place the chip closer to the diode, inductor and capacitors.

Comment: I solved it yesterday, I needed to put a jumper on the EN and GND pins and immediately after put a jumper on GPIO0 and GND, after that, the code was loading without problems. For the next designs I will put EN and RESET buttons. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

I solved it yesterday, I needed to put a jumper on the EN and GND pins and immediately after put a jumper on GPIO0 and GND, after that, the code was loading without problems. For the next designs I will put EN and RESET buttons. Thanks everybody

Comment: You could also use the esp-prog programmer. It saves you the cp210x, cost, power and space. + for finding out yourself. Well done.